# How to call function in an HTML attribute that only accepts string values / literals?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, function, pug

I am having issues calling a function within an attribute in this jade file:

**test.jade**

```
script
    - function myFunction(str) {
        some regex on str, say, to filter out all full stops and 
        return the new string.
    }

    .container-fluid
        .row
            .col-md-12
                div(ng-repeat='thing in things')
                    button(popovertext='{{thing.description()}}', popover-trigger='mouseenter')
```

The expression in the popovertext attribute prints strings just fine for each thing in things (as done by ng-repeat) without calling the function. But as far as I'm told, the popovertext only accepts string values, so when I did something like

```
                    button(popovertext='myFunction({{thing.description()}})')
```

It actually prints out myFunction(....the original string....), which basically means it doesn't recognise my function at all. I'm supposed to call the function in this jade file and not externally in another .js file, because apparently any attribute that doesn't have 'ng-' doesn't communicate with controllers at all?

How can I possibly get around this?

---

Also, I am very confused regarding when I should put a "-" in front of my line of code. Am I right in saying that, for jade, I need it for var, function, and return?

Comment: I don't known much about Jade, but in Angular is not matter of having an "ng-something" attribute, is a matter of having that function or data bind to the controller's scope.

Comment: Sorry it toke to long to write the example:
[here plunk not working](http://plnkr.co/edit/M69yjn?p=catalogue)

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to get around this is setting the field called descriptionString for all the thing object. You can do that in your controller:

```
angular.forEach(things, function(thing){
  thing.descriptionString = thing.description();
});
```

The rest is easy:

```
button(popovertext='{{thing.descriptionString}}', popover-trigger='mouseenter')
```